# `window.onerror` hook not being called when throwing exception inside Promise

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise

I've added an error hook using `window.onerror`, but when I `throw` inside of the cb to a `.then` of a `Promise` the hook doesn't fire. Is there a way to make the hook fire? I don't want to have to add a `.catch`

```
window.onerror = () => console.log('an error')

new Promise(_ => _())
  .then(() => {
    throw 'err'
  })

//the hook doesn't fire
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An exception thrown inside a `.then()` handler is automatically caught by the promise and it turns the promise into a rejected promise so the exception does not bubble up to where it would be be seen by `window.onerrror`.

If you don't have a handler for the rejected promise, then you should get an `unhandledrejection` event as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unhandledrejection_event).